# Waiting for didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification

In AppDelegate.m I have:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"deviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

And in my SendViewController.m I have:

```
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    deviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"deviceToken"];
    NSLog(@"%@", deviceToken);
```

But returns old deviceToken. I must to wait for some time registration token. How I can do this?

Comment: old device token means? Explain clearly

Comment: @Rajan Maheshwari For example, if the first request, it returns nil, and if the second, return the first value.